# Recursively select the maximum that is unique

Tags: sql-server, recursion, max

I have the following data for fields `A`, `B`, `C`:

```
A  B  C
-- -- --
1  1  90
1  2  99
1  3  75
2  1  60
2  2  54
2  3  95
3  1  85
3  2  80
3  3  9
4  1  80
4  2  85
4  3  86
4  4  87
```

I need to find the the pair of `A` and `B` that produces the maximum `C` value and then select the next maximum so that it does not contain either `A` or `B`.  In the above data, the first attempt selects `1, 2` because `99` is maximum.  The second pass excludes all pairs with either 1 or 2 and therefore we are left with  `3 3`, `4 3`, and `4 4`, and the second maximum is `4 4`. The process continues and the result is:

```
A  B  C
-- -- --
1  2  99
4  4  87
3  3  9
```

How can I do this using SQL?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, something else?

Comment: @littleBobbyTables I am using SQL Server

Comment: I've added the `sql-server` tag for you.  In the future, you should use appropriate question tags for best visibility, especially since this solution may differ depending on the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a table (a int,b int,c int)
insert into @a values (1, 1, 90)
,(1, 2, 99)
,(1, 3, 75)
,(1, 3, 75)
,(2, 1, 60)
,(2, 2 ,54)
,(2, 3, 95)
,(3, 1, 85)
,(3, 2, 80)
,(3, 3, 9)
,(4, 1, 80)
,(4, 2, 85)
,(4, 3 ,86)
,(4, 4, 87);
Declare @rct int

Select top 1 *
into #tmp
from @a
Order by c desc

Select @rct=@@ROWCOUNT
While @rct>0
    begin
     Insert into #tmp
     Select Top 1 a.*
     from @a a
     Left Join #tmp on #tmp.A=a.A or #tmp.B=a.B or #tmp.b=a.A or #tmp.A=a.b
     Where #tmp.a is null and #tmp.b is null
     Order by C desc 
     Select @rct=@@ROWCOUNT
    end

Select * from #tmp
order by c desc
Drop table #tmp
```

with 600000 rows you could try this attempt

```
declare @a table (a int,b int,c int)
insert into @a values (1, 1, 90)
,(1, 2, 99)
,(1, 3, 75)
,(1, 3, 75)
,(2, 1, 60)
,(2, 2 ,54)
,(2, 3, 95)
,(3, 1, 85)
,(3, 2, 80)
,(3, 3, 9)
,(4, 1, 80)
,(4, 2, 85)
,(4, 3 ,86)
,(4, 4, 87);
Declare @rct int

Select a,b,c 
into #work
from @a   --  your big table
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [i_a] ON #work (a)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [i_b] ON #work (b)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [i_c] ON #work (c)

Select top 1 *
into #tmp
from #work
Order by c desc

Select * 
into #final
from #tmp

Delete #work 
from #tmp
where #work.a=#tmp.a or #work.b=#tmp.a or #work.a=#tmp.b or #work.b=#tmp.b

While (Select COUNT(*) from #work) >0
    begin
    delete from #tmp

    insert into #tmp
    Select top 1 *  
    from #work
    Order by c desc

    insert into #final
    Select *    
    from #tmp

    Delete #work 
    from #tmp
    where #work.a=#tmp.a or #work.b=#tmp.a or #work.a=#tmp.b or #work.b=#tmp.b
    end 

drop table #work
drop table #tmp
Select * from #final
drop table #final
```

Comment: thank you this is very helpful but I am having a difficult time completing the code on a real database of 600,000 records.  Is there someway of using group by ID to repeat these calculations only within one ID?